# Why doesn't DriveImage XML recognize my partitions in destination step?

Tags: windows, backup, disk-cloning, driveimagexml

I am trying to copy my current windows 7 installation over to my second HD using DriveImage XML; however, although it recognizes my drive partitions in the initial step of drive-to-drive, when I am prompted to select the destination partition, the only option I have is the entire destination drive (not the partition I was wanting to put it on). I don't want to wipe the entire drive, I just want to put the windows installation (currently on C drive) on a ~400G partition (on Y drive) and boot from it there.

[image]

Here is my current disk partitioning scheme:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you created volumes D and Y on a "dynamic disk". Little other than
Microsoft software will deal with those things. You should recreate them as
simple volumes on a "basic" disk.